# preg_replace with arrays of different sizes

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I know that the answer is probably simple and I am just not seeing it.
This code gets me an array of "tags" in the layout (eg `[[tag]]`), and I have an array of replacements that comes in with the request (`$this->data`). My first inclination was to use `preg_match_all` to get an array of all the tags and just pass in both arrays:

```
if(isset($this->layout))
{
    ob_start();
    include(VIEWS.'layouts/'.$this->layout.'.phtml');
    $this->layout = ob_get_contents();

    preg_match_all('/\[\[.*\]\]/', $this->layout, $tags);
    print preg_replace($tags, $this->data, $this->layout);
}
```

But the arrays are not the same length (most of the time). The layout might reuse some tags, and the passed in data variables might not include some tags in the layout.

I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this than doing a `foreach` and building the output in iterations.

This project is way too small to implement a full templating engine like Smarty or Twig... it is actually just a few pages and a few replacements. My client just wants a simple way to add things like page titles and email recipients, etc.

Any advice would be appreciated. Like I said, I am positive that it is something simple that I am overlooking.

EDIT:
`$this->data` is an array of replacement text that look like:

`tag => replacement_text`

EDIT 2:
If I user `preg_match_all('/\[\[(.*)\]\]/', $this->layout, $tags);` the array includes JUST the tags (no `[[]]`), I just need a way to match them up with the array of replacement strings in `$this->data`.

Comment: What's in `$this->data`?

Comment: Look into [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Comment: What are you doing with `ob_get_contents()`? Couldn't those 3 lines be replaced with `$this->layout = file_get_contents(VIEWS.'layouts/'.$this->layout.'.phtml');`?

Comment: @Barmar I'm guessing those templates contain PHP to be interpreted.

Comment: @Barmar more will be happening with that in the future. For now, yes it could be replaced... but I plan on building on that buffer.

Comment: @Nick ```$this->data = tag => replacement_text```

Comment: FYI, the keys of `$this->data` are ignored by `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `preg_replace(array_keys($this->data), array_values($this->data), $this->layout);`?

Comment: @Barmar I think that's very close - just need to allow for `[[...]]` around the tag name. Will you post?

Comment: Right, I was about to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this job, creating an array of search strings and replacements from `$this->data`:

```
$search = array_map(function ($s) { return "[[$s]]"; }, array_keys($this->data));
$replacements = array_values($this->data);
echo str_replace($search, $replacements, $this->layout);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2OHHo)

Comment: You're right, with all the escaping I added in my similar solution, it's turned `preg_replace` into `str_replace`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah - as long as there's no `[[` in the tag names `preg_replace` shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[\[(?<tag>.*?)]]/', function ($matches) {
  return $this->data[$matches['tag']] ?? $matches[0];
}, $this->layout);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/I9Vvh**

Shorter PHP 7.4 version:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\[\[(?<tag>.*?)]]/', fn($matches) => 
  $this->data[$matches['tag']] ?? $matches[0], $this->layout);
```

Edited with the `?? $matches[0]` (courtesy of @Barmar) -- this is basically the same answer, just leaving it in case the PHP 7.4 syntax is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get `$tags` by matching `$this->layout`, the information is all in the keys of `$this->data`. You just need to add `[[...]]` around the keys.

```
$tags = array_map(function($key) { 
    return '/\[\[' . preg_quote($key) . '\]\]'; 
}, array_keys($this->data));
```

Another solution is to use `preg_replace_callback()` to look the tag up in `$this->data`;

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/', function($matches) {
    return $this->data[$matches[1]] ?? $matches[0];
}, $this->layout);
```

Note that I changed the regexp to use a non-greedy quantifier; your regexp will match from the beginning of the first tag to the end of the last tag.

If the tag isn't found in `$this->data`, `?? $matches[0]` leaves it unchanged.

Comment: Yes. I see it. I figured it was simpler than I was looking for... I don't have the reputation to upvote, but this is +1 for sure. Thanks.